# Is it possible to create custiom tags in (X)HTML (5)?

Tags: xml, html, xhtml

I want to write an (X)HTML document that contains a text in a blackletter font. In German, it's convention to typeset foreign words in an antiqua font when the document's base font is a blackletter font. Because this is a semantic markup that may appear quite often, I dislike using a `<span class="fw">` or similar.

Is it possible to define a new tag `<fw>` (for foreign word) in (X)HTML, so that I can markup by semantics? If yes, is that supported by modern browsers? Is there anything special to take care of when using this with a stylesheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XHTML is XML, and it's still XML if you add your own tags in your own namespace. You could consider using your own XML vocabulary and using client-side XSLT to render it (with the new Saxon-CE product, you can even use XSLT 2.0). However, if this is the only "semantic" tagging you want to add, it's probably overkill - just use `<span class="fw">` as suggested.

Answer (score 3):

For the purpose you're describing, it could make sense to use the `<i>` tag. While `<i>` meant "italics" in the past, in HTML5 [it is specified like](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-b-and-i-tags/):

> The i element represents a span of text in an alternate voice or mood,
>   or otherwise offset from the normal prose, such as a taxonomic
>   designation, a technical term, an idiomatic phrase from another
>   language, a thought, a ship name, or some other prose whose typical
>   typographic presentation is italicized.

Note that when you want to emphasize text via italics, the `<em>` tag remains available for your use and remains more appropriate for that task. And see the link above for the new use of the `<b>` tag, another alternative to adding a custom (invalid) tag.

To answer your question more directly: It's not possible to add a tag and remain valid HTML5.

Comment: Good answer. I would suggest that even better semantics can be achieved by adding a `lang` attribute to the `<i>` element. That flags it as a foreign word very clearly. It also allows css to target foreign words through an `i[lang]` selector.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.  Longer answer: not a good idea.

BTW, `<div style="antiqua">` will not work, maybe you mean `<div style="font-family: antiqua">`  A better solution IMO would be `<span class="fw">`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is entirely possible to create your own tags with the help of JavaScript. However, I strongly advise against this practice (unless it's for the following use).

Typically, this method is used to force HTML5-support with older browsers. It's more of a workaround than anything else, and should be treated as such.

You can create support for any tag (even custom ones) by using just this tiny bit of JS code in the beginning of your HTML document: `document.createElement('tagname');` You can also style these custom tags just as you normally would with anything else; CSS or inline.

Please note that your custom tags will not validate. It's an ugly practice to use just for the sake of the designer's personal taste.

As always though, I strongly encourage that you use what's already out there, and name elements by using **Classes**.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about how this is possible using JavaScript?

Comment: Thank you for the answer! What happens if I use a custom tag and just define a style for it in my CSS-file? Will browsers just treat it like a `<span>`?

Comment: Browsers will treat it as if it were a pre-determined tag all along.

Answer (score 0):

HTML and XHTML specifications define the allowed tags, but nothing really prevents you from using whatever tags you like. Modern browsers generally recognize the tags as defining elements, and you can style those elements and process them with client-side scripts.

However, as you can see from the answers to several questions here (search for “custom tags” for example), there are several reasons to avoid that in most cases.

There simply is no HTML markup for “foreign word”, and there is no HTML markup for most semantic distinctions we can make. We can live with that. For the most of it, no software really cares about even those few distinctions that we *can* make in HTML.

If you don’t like `span`, you can use `font` (since what you really want to make is a font distinction), or maybe `a` for brevity. (Without `href`, `a` is really semantically empty, or free, like `span` is.)

You can additionally use a `lang` attribute, e.g. `<font class="fw" lang="en">dummy</font>`. It may make the markup look a bit more semantic, and it may become relevant in special cases (in speech synthesis in some situations, in spelling checks, etc.).

Comment: Well, I can life with span. My question was only about whether it is possible to create custom tags in (x)html.... I thought using some xml trickery one might be able to archieve that. (I mean, you can embed whole namespaces using xml...)

Comment: FUZxxl, no trickery is needed, except for old versions of IE (and it’s JavaScript trickery that is needed for it). Namespaces are relevant if you want to use tags that have *predefined* meanings to browsers, like MathML and HTML tags mixed.

Comment: @FUZxxl - The problem is not so much using a made-up element, but associating a meaning with it, such that it conveys the semantics you want it to. There's no HTML or XML trickery that allows you to assign semantics to a new element. To do that, you must write a specification that others are prepared to read and to accept your definition of the element.